# How to get the non public property of an object and its value at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, propertygrid

How to get all non  public properties of an object and its value at the same time so that the object can be given to a property grid at run time to populate its values.

the scenario is like this whenever treeviewitem of TreeView is selected, propertygrid is changed automatically as selection changes in treeview.

here is the xaml file.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfExperiment.AdditionalProperty"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
               xmlns:wpg="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"

            >

    <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="RadioButtons">
                <RadioButton Margin="0,3" Content="{Binding .}" GroupName="radios" Checked="Item_Checked" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SortTypes" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="wpg:PropertySort"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>


    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">


        <wpg:WpfPropertyGrid  x:Name="PropertyGrid1" 
            Margin="20,20,118,21" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HelpVisible="{Binding ElementName=ShowDescrip, Path=IsChecked}" 
            ToolbarVisible="{Binding ElementName=ShowToolbar, Path=IsChecked}"
            PropertySort="{Binding ElementName=ComboSort, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10" >Selected Object:</TextBlock>
           <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RadioButtons}" Height="100" Visibility="{Binding }" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,3" >Selection Type:</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,3" >Features:</TextBlock>
            <CheckBox Name="ShowDescrip" Margin="0,3,0,3" Content="Help Visible" />
            <CheckBox Name="ShowToolbar" Margin="0,3,0,3" IsChecked="True" Content="Toolbar Visible" />
            <ComboBox Name="ComboSort" Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="95" FontSize="10"
                SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortTypes}}" />
        </StackPanel>



    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

AdditionalProperty.xaml.cs

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AdditionalProperty.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AdditionalProperty : UserControl
    {
        static private Person Person;

        public AdditionalProperty(Person _person)
        {
            Person = _person;
        }

        // names must match the data members
        private object[] ItemArray = { "Person" };
        public AdditionalProperty()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.ItemList.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["RadioButtons"] as DataTemplate;
                this.ItemList.ItemsSource = this.ItemArray;

        }


        private void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Source is RadioButton)
            {

                object selected = this.GetType().GetField("Person",   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this);

               this. PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = selected;




            }
        }



    }
}
```

this usercontrol is embedded in a window control like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExperiment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            xmlns:wpg="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExperiment"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

 <local:AdditionalProperty Grid.Column="1"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       private Person Person = new Person("Shakti");
       // names must match the data members
       private object[] ItemArray = { "Person"};

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
              new AdditionalProperty(Person);

        }
}
```

WpfPropertyGrid code:

```
namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public enum PropertySort
    {
        NoSort = 0,
        Alphabetical = 1,
        Categorized = 2,
        CategorizedAlphabetical = 3
    }; 
    /// <summary>WPF Native PropertyGrid class, uses Workflow Foundation's PropertyInspector</summary>
    public class WpfPropertyGrid : Grid
    {
        #region Private fields
        private WorkflowDesigner Designer;
        private MethodInfo RefreshMethod;
        private MethodInfo OnSelectionChangedMethod;
        private MethodInfo IsInAlphaViewMethod;
        private TextBlock SelectionTypeLabel;
        private Control PropertyToolBar;
        private Border HelpText;
        private GridSplitter Splitter;
        private double HelpTextHeight = 60;
        #endregion

        #region Public properties
        /// <summary>Get or sets the selected object. Can be null.</summary>
        public object SelectedObject
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedObjectProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedObjectProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>Get or sets the selected object collection. Returns empty array by default.</summary>
        public object[] SelectedObjects
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedObjectsProperty) as object[]; }
            set { SetValue(SelectedObjectsProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>XAML information with PropertyGrid's font and color information</summary>
        /// <seealso>Documentation for WorkflowDesigner.PropertyInspectorFontAndColorData</seealso>
        public string FontAndColorData
        {
            set
            {
                Designer.PropertyInspectorFontAndColorData = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>Shows the description area on the top of the control</summary>
        public bool HelpVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HelpVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HelpVisibleProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>Shows the tolbar on the top of the control</summary>
        public bool ToolbarVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ToolbarVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ToolbarVisibleProperty, value); }
        }
        public PropertySort PropertySort
        {
            get { return (PropertySort)GetValue(PropertySortProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertySortProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Dependency properties registration
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedObjectProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedObject", typeof(object), typeof(WpfPropertyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedObjectPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedObjectsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedObjects", typeof(object[]), typeof(WpfPropertyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new object[0], FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedObjectsPropertyChanged, CoerceSelectedObjects));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HelpVisibleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HelpVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(WpfPropertyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, HelpVisiblePropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarVisibleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ToolbarVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(WpfPropertyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, ToolbarVisiblePropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertySortProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertySort", typeof(PropertySort), typeof(WpfPropertyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PropertySort.CategorizedAlphabetical, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, PropertySortPropertyChanged));
        #endregion

        #region Dependency properties events
        private static object CoerceSelectedObject(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = d as WpfPropertyGrid;

            object[] collection = pg.GetValue(SelectedObjectsProperty) as object[];

            return collection.Length == 0 ? null : value;
        }
        private static object CoerceSelectedObjects(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = d as WpfPropertyGrid;

            object single = pg.GetValue(SelectedObjectsProperty);

            return single == null ? new object[0] : value;
        }

        private static void SelectedObjectPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = source as WpfPropertyGrid;
            pg.CoerceValue(SelectedObjectsProperty);

            if (e.NewValue == null)
            {
                pg.OnSelectionChangedMethod.Invoke(pg.Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { null });
                pg.SelectionTypeLabel.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                var context = new EditingContext();
                var mtm = new ModelTreeManager(context);
                mtm.Load(e.NewValue);
                Selection selection = Selection.Select(context, mtm.Root);

                pg.OnSelectionChangedMethod.Invoke(pg.Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { selection });
                pg.SelectionTypeLabel.Text = e.NewValue.GetType().Name;
            }

            pg.ChangeHelpText(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        }
        private static void SelectedObjectsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = source as WpfPropertyGrid;
            pg.CoerceValue(SelectedObjectsProperty);

            object[] collection = e.NewValue as object[];

            if (collection.Length == 0)
            {
                pg.OnSelectionChangedMethod.Invoke(pg.Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { null });
                pg.SelectionTypeLabel.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                bool same = true;
                Type first = null;

                var context = new EditingContext();
                var mtm = new ModelTreeManager(context);
                Selection selection = null;

                // Accumulates the selection and determines the type to be shown in the top of the PG
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
                {
                    mtm.Load(collection[i]);
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        selection = Selection.Select(context, mtm.Root);
                        first = collection[0].GetType();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selection = Selection.Union(context, mtm.Root);
                        if (!collection[i].GetType().Equals(first))
                            same = false;
                    }
                }

                pg.OnSelectionChangedMethod.Invoke(pg.Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { selection });
                pg.SelectionTypeLabel.Text = same ? first.Name + " <multiple>" : "Object <multiple>";
            }

            pg.ChangeHelpText(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        }
        private static void HelpVisiblePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = source as WpfPropertyGrid;

            if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
            {
                if (e.NewValue.Equals(true))
                {
                    pg.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(5);
                    pg.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(pg.HelpTextHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    pg.HelpTextHeight = pg.RowDefinitions[2].Height.Value;
                    pg.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(0);
                    pg.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);
                }
            }
        }
        private static void ToolbarVisiblePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = source as WpfPropertyGrid;
            pg.PropertyToolBar.Visibility = e.NewValue.Equals(true) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        private static void PropertySortPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfPropertyGrid pg = source as WpfPropertyGrid;
            PropertySort sort = (PropertySort)e.NewValue;

            bool isAlpha = (sort == PropertySort.Alphabetical || sort == PropertySort.NoSort);
            pg.IsInAlphaViewMethod.Invoke(pg.Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { isAlpha });
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Default constructor, creates the UIElements including a PropertyInspector</summary>
        public WpfPropertyGrid()
        {
            this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0) });
            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0) });

            this.Designer = new WorkflowDesigner();
            TextBlock title = new TextBlock()
            {
                Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap,
                TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
            };
            TextBlock descrip = new TextBlock()
            {
                Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis
            };
            DockPanel dock = new DockPanel()
            {
                Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                LastChildFill = true,
                Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 3, 0)
            };

            title.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Top);
            dock.Children.Add(title);
            dock.Children.Add(descrip);
            this.HelpText = new Border()
            {
                Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush,
                Background = SystemColors.ControlBrush,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                Child = dock
            };
            this.Splitter = new GridSplitter()
            {
                Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                ResizeDirection = GridResizeDirection.Rows,
                Height = 5,
                HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
            };

            var inspector = Designer.PropertyInspectorView;
            inspector.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            inspector.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Stretch);

            this.Splitter.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
            this.Splitter.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

            this.HelpText.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
            this.HelpText.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

            Binding binding = new Binding("Parent.Background");
            title.SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, binding);
            descrip.SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, binding);

            this.Children.Add(inspector);
            this.Children.Add(this.Splitter);
            this.Children.Add(this.HelpText);

            Type inspectorType = inspector.GetType();
            var props = inspectorType.GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            var methods = inspectorType.GetMethods(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            this.RefreshMethod = inspectorType.GetMethod("RefreshPropertyList",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            this.IsInAlphaViewMethod = inspectorType.GetMethod("set_IsInAlphaView",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            this.OnSelectionChangedMethod = inspectorType.GetMethod("OnSelectionChanged",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            this.SelectionTypeLabel = inspectorType.GetMethod("get_SelectionTypeLabel",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Invoke(inspector, new object[0]) as TextBlock;
            this.PropertyToolBar = inspectorType.GetMethod("get_PropertyToolBar",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Invoke(inspector, new object[0]) as Control;
            inspectorType.GetEvent("GotFocus").AddEventHandler(this,
                Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RoutedEventHandler), this, "GotFocusHandler", false));

            this.SelectionTypeLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        /// <summary>Updates the PropertyGrid's properties</summary>
        public void RefreshPropertyList()
        {
            RefreshMethod.Invoke(Designer.PropertyInspectorView, new object[] { false });
        }

        /// <summary>Traps the change of focused property and updates the help text</summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Not used</param>
        /// <param name="args">Points to the source control containing the selected property</param>
        private void GotFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            //if (args.OriginalSource is TextBlock)
            //{
            string title = string.Empty;
            string descrip = string.Empty;
            var theSelectedObjects = this.GetValue(SelectedObjectsProperty) as object[];

            if (theSelectedObjects != null && theSelectedObjects.Length > 0)
            {
                Type first = theSelectedObjects[0].GetType();
                for (int i = 1; i < theSelectedObjects.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!theSelectedObjects[i].GetType().Equals(first))
                    {
                        ChangeHelpText(title, descrip);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                object data = (args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
                PropertyInfo propEntry = data.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyEntry");
                if (propEntry == null)
                {
                    propEntry = data.GetType().GetProperty("ParentProperty");
                }

                if (propEntry != null)
                {
                    object propEntryValue = propEntry.GetValue(data, null);
                    string propName = propEntryValue.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(propEntryValue, null) as string;
                    title = propEntryValue.GetType().GetProperty("DisplayName").GetValue(propEntryValue, null) as string;
                    PropertyInfo property = theSelectedObjects[0].GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                    object[] attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);

                    if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                        descrip = (attrs[0] as DescriptionAttribute).Description;
                }
                ChangeHelpText(title, descrip);
            }
            //}
        }
        /// <summary>Changes the text help area contents</summary>
        /// <param name="title">Title in bold</param>
        /// <param name="descrip">Description with ellipsis</param>
        private void ChangeHelpText(string title, string descrip)
        {
            DockPanel dock = this.HelpText.Child as DockPanel;
            (dock.Children[0] as TextBlock).Text = title;
            (dock.Children[1] as TextBlock).Text = descrip;
        }
    }
}
```

Person class:

```
  public class Person
    {
        public enum Gender { Male, Female }

        #region private fields
        private string[] _Names = new string[3];
        #endregion

        // The following properties are wrapping an array of strings
        #region Public Properties
        [Category("Name")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName
        {
            set { _Names[0] = value; }
            get { return _Names[0]; }
        }

        [Category("Name")]
        [DisplayName("Mid Name")]
        public string MidName
        {
            set { _Names[1] = value; }
            get { return _Names[1]; }
        }

        [Category("Name")]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName
        {
            set { _Names[2] = value; }
            get { return _Names[2]; }
        }

        // The following are autoimplemented properties (C# 3.0 and up)
        [Category("Characteristics")]
        [DisplayName("Gender")]
        public Gender PersonGender { get; set; }

        [Category("Characteristics")]
        [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [Category("Characteristics")]
        public int Income { get; set; }

        // Other cases of hidden read-only property and formatted property
        [DisplayName("GUID"), ReadOnly(true), Browsable(true)]   // many attributes defined in the same row
        public string GuidStr
        {
            get { return Guid.ToString(); }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]  // this property will not be displayed
        public System.Guid Guid
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        #endregion

        public Person(string name)
        {
            // default values
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                _Names[i] = name;
            this.PersonGender = Gender.Male;
            this.Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, MidName, LastName).Trim().Replace("  ", " ");
        }
    }
```

I am not able to understand why part of this code is returning null:

```
object selected = **this.GetType().GetField("Person",   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)**.GetValue(this);
```

just for reference this code has been adapted from [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid]

Comment: where is Person field defined ?

Comment: its here in AdditionalProperty usercontrol as  static private Person Person;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do :

```
this.GetType().GetField("Person",   
     System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(this)
```

Suggession: do not call instances with the name of the itself. Avoid confusion.

Comment: does not help, still the part before .GetValue(this) returns null.

Comment: where you call this method ?

Comment: just to check, if there is a radiobutton on the usercontrol when radiobutton is pressed that time private void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) is called. please check the code above. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaktisaxena: I see it declared as Static, so use corresponding Binging flag to it. I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. it works like a charm.would be great if u can explain the reason behind it?

Comment: you need to tell to the function among what fields it has to search: so we say search in current type the field with name "Public" among private or protected (non public) *and* it has to be static too.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way out the properties and values can be loaded when usercontrol is loaded. can you please give me some insight in to it?

Comment: if you are talking about *visualizing* properties on control appearance, use DataBinding, it will tskr care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PropertyInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this. Try something like this:

```
List<object> privatePropertyValues = new List<object>();
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0}  Type: {1},  Value: {2}", propertyInfo.Name, 
    //  propertyInfo.PropertyType, propertyInfo.GetValue(this));
    privatePropertyValues.Add(propertyInfo.GetValue(this));
}
```

UPDATE >>>

To get just one property, you can use the `Type.GetProperty` method:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
```

I think that this is all correct, but I can't test it at the moment, so let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: but the thing is that I need it as an object so that it can be given to propertygrid selectedObject. as a result, propertygrid would populate the contents automatically.

Comment: You need the property value as an object? Can you really not adapt this code to do that? I'll update it.